# Does a continuous function preserve Bolzano-Weierstrass property?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X,Y$ be arbitrary topological spaces with $X$ satisfying the Bolzano-Weierstrass property (i.e. every infinite subset has some accumulation point) and let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous function, does $f(X)$ satisfy the B-W property?

I tried to prove it does by contradiction as follows:

Let's assume $f(X)$ doesn't have the BWP, so there must be some infinite subset $A$ wich has not any accumulation point, hence it's is closed. Because $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(A)$ is also closed and infinite and because $X$ has the BWP there is some accumulation point of $f^{-1}(A)$ which is contained in it, let's call $x_0$ one of such points. Now, $f(x_0)$ is an isolated point of A, so $\{f(x_0)\}$ is an open neighborhood of $f(x_0)$ (with the relative topology of $f(X)$ as a subspace of $Y$).
This means that $f^{-1}(f(x_0))$ is an open neighborhood of $x_0$ which contains other points different than $x_0$. But this doesn't lead me to a contradiction since in principle $f$ could be locally constant at $x_0$. Is there some reason why this cannot happen? Or maybe continuous function doesn't actually preserve BWP, if that's the case could someone provide a counterexample? Constant functions doesn't seem to work because they have finite image, so I thought maybe a locally constant function with infinite image, but I couldn't build up an explicit example.

EDIT to avoid future missunderstandings: What I called 'accumulation point' above is what usually is refered in english as 'limit point'. Explicitly $a$ is an accumulation (limit) point of a set $A$ of a topological space $X$ if every open set containing $a$ intersected with $A$ contains some point different than $a$

Comment: This reminds me of something similar: Let $X$ be a $T_1$ space and let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous surjection. Let $D$ be a closed discrete sub-space of $Y.$ Then $X$ has a closed discrete sub-space $C$ of equal  cardinal to $D.$ Proof: For $d\in D$  choose $g(d)\in f^{-1}\{d\}.$  Show that $C=g(D$) is a closed discrete sub-space of $X.$

Comment: What is your definition of accumulation point? It seems like a limit point.

Comment: My example below shows exactly this locally constant problem...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually false if "accumulation point" = "limit point" where $x$ is a limit point of $A$ iff every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A\setminus\{x\}$.
Your B-W property is then called "limit point compact"

A counterexample: Let $Y = \mathbb{N}$ as a discrete space and let $X = Y \times \{0,1\}$ where $\{0,1\}$ has the indiscrete (trivial) topology with no non-trivial open sets. Let $f= \pi_Y$ be the projection onto $Y$, which is continuous. 
$X$ is limit point compact: if $A \subseteq X$, and $(x,i) \in A$, then $(x,i')$ is a limit point of $A$, where $i' \in \{0,1\}\setminus\{i\}$, because any product open set that contains $(x,i)$ also contains $(x,i')$ and vice versa. But $Y$ is infinite discrete so not limit point compact.

If $X$ is $T_1$ then (here our example is not even $T_0$) limit point compact is equivalent to "strong limit point compact": every infinite set $A$ has an ($\omega$-)accumulation point, i.e. an $x \in X$ such that every neighbourhood of $x$ contains *infinitely many* points from $A$. This property *is* preserved by continuous functions:

Suppose $X$ is strong limit point compact, and $f:X \to Y$ is continuous.
Let $A \subseteq f[X]$ be infinite and let $\{y_n: n \in \omega\}$ be an enumeration ($y_n \neq y_m$ for $n \neq m$) of a countably infinite subset of $A$ which means that we have for all $n$ we have $x_n \in X$ such that $f(x_n) = y_n$. Then clearly, $n \neq m$ implies $x_n \neq x_m$ as well, so $\{x_n: n \in \omega\}$ is an infinite subset of $X$. So this has a strong limit point $x$. Now let $y = f(x) \in f[X]$.
If $O$ is any open set containing $y$ then $f^{-1}[O]$ is open by continuity and contains $x$, so there are infinitely many $n$ with $x_n \in f^{-1}[O]$. All those $n$ also obey $y_n = f(x_n) \in O$. So $y$ is a strong limit point of $A$, and $f[X]$ is strong limit point compact.

So your original statement is true for $T_1$ spaces $X$. We then get even a (slightly) stronger property than B-W in $Y$ (without assuming anything extra on $Y$), namely strong limit compact.

Comment: Hello there! Yes, my definition of accumulation point coincides with limit point. Sorry for that, I guess it's something cultural, we don't even use that term for sequences (according to wikipedia accumulation point is used as a synonim of cluster point of a sequence, which we call 'agglomeration point' of a sequence)... I like your counterexample, very simple and easy to follow, but I still don't realize what's wrong then with the proof provided by Hellen, I need to think a little more about it... Btw so it is not common in english to say a set 'has the B-W property' to mean what I ment?

Comment: @laflaca $f(x)$ could be the same as $f(x_n)$

Comment: Sure, I got it!   ; )

Comment: @laflaca for me a cluster point of a sequence $(x_n)$ is an $x$ such that for all neighbourhoods $O$ of $x$ and for all $n$ there is some $m > n$ with $x_m \in O$. This need not even be a limit point of $\{x_n: n \in\omega\}$, we could have a constant subsequence.

Comment: sure, I just meant to say that wikipedia agrees with you on the definition of limit point, and it also agrees on that definition of cluster point you gave but it also use the term 'accumulation point' as a synonym of cluster point (which is not the usage I was giving to it). My comment on Hellen's answer identifying a cluster point of a sequence with a limit point of its image is mistaken, precisesely for that reason. But I couldn't edit it, when I was going to post the edit it was too late...

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x_n)=y_n\in f(X)$ be a sequence of different points. Then, $x_n$ are different too. Passing to a subsequence, there is an $x$ such that $x_n$ accumulates in $x$. Let $V\ni y=f(x)$ be an open subset of $Y$. Then $U=f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ and contains $x$. Therefore some $x_n$ lies in $U$. Therefore $y_n=f(x_n)$ lies in $V$. This means that $y_n$ accumulates in $y$.

Comment: Of course, I forgot the usefulness of the axiom  of choice. Thank you!

Comment: There is no use of the axiom of choice in this argument.

Comment: @RobArthan To get $x_n$.

Comment: @RobArthan There is in **my** argument.

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer given by Hellen fixes what was missing in my reasoning. It's great that you can give a proof without using the AC, but this one is still a good answer to my question

Comment: @RobArthan I rather be proud of using an axiom than stating a falsehood.

Comment: You seem to be confusing sequentially compact and B-W here, or what do *you* mean by "accumulates in $x$"? @Hellen

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I think she means that $x$ is a  cluster point of the sequence because it is an accumulation (limit) point of its image

Comment: @Hellen you cannot show that $f(x_n) \neq f(x)$. See my example where this is why things go wrong

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes, you're right, I see it now

Comment: @RobArthan countable choice *is* needed to simultaneously choose all $x_n$ at the same time so that they form a set.  But countable choice is pretty uncontroversial.

Answer (score 0):

Continuity alone has nothing to do with Bolzano-Weierstrass.

Returning to definitions often helps. You need to show that the **range** of $f$ is well-ordered, and, in addition, continuous.